# QSerialPort write() not transmitting data

Tags: serial-port, qt6

I have a maddening problem with `QSerialPort` where `write()` does not transmit any data out. Below is the class where I am connecting and disconnecting from the serial port (/dev/ttyUSB2).

```
bool pcon::com_connect()
{
    c_serialPort.setPortName(c_com_port);
    c_serialPort.setBaudRate(c_baud_rate);
    c_serialPort.setParity(c_parity);
    c_serialPort.setStopBits(c_stop_bits);
    c_serialPort.setFlowControl(c_flow_ctl);

    c_connected_status = c_serialPort.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);

    return c_connected_status;
}

void pcon::com_disconnect()
{
    c_serialPort.close();
    c_connected_status = false;
}

QString pcon::tx_rx(QString tx)
{
    //0. Build the PCON TX String
    QString toCHKSUM = QString::asprintf("%02X", c_addr) + tx;
    QString FromCHKSUM = chksum(toCHKSUM);

    QString outstring = ":" + toCHKSUM + FromCHKSUM + "\n\r";

    //1. TX the PCON TX String.
    const QByteArray tx_ba = outstring.toUtf8();
    qint64 w_result = c_serialPort.write(tx_ba.data());
    
    c_rx_ba = c_serialPort.readLine();
    c_rx = QString(c_rx_ba);

    //3. Print out debug information.
    qDebug() << "Class: pcon on " << c_com_port << " Function: tx_rx, TX: " << outstring << " RX: " << c_rx << " Write Result: " << w_result;

    return c_rx;
}
```

Below are the results from the `tx_rx()` function. Here I am attempting to turn the servo on and off. The servo never responds.

```
Class: pcon on  "/dev/ttyUSB2"  Function: tx_rx, TX:  ":01050403FF00F4\n\r"  RX:  ""  Write Result:  17
Class: pcon on  "/dev/ttyUSB2"  Function: tx_rx, TX:  ":010504030000F3\n\r"  RX:  ""  Write Result:  17
```

Qt says the call to `write()` completed successfully and wrote 17 characters, but no data is written out to the serial port. I have verified that the problem isn't a permission issue or a problem with the device I am trying to talk to it seems if there is a bug in the QSerialPort library in Qt. I can use cutecom to talk to /dev/ttyUSB2 without any issues,

cuteCOM talking to /dev/ttyUSB2 turning servo on/off:
[image: cuteCOM talking to /dev/ttyUSB2 turning servo on/off]

I have tried Qt version 6.2.4 and 6.4.0 with the same results.

Why is `write()` returning success when no data is transmitted?

Comment: That's typically a problem with the flow control.  We can't tell from the snippet what c_flow_ctl might mean or whether the device is turning on the flow control signals as required.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me immediately after writing data to the stream to cause waiting for recording.

```
m_serial->write(data); //QByteArray with some data
m_serial->waitForBytesWritten();
```

Why write() just doesn't work, I didn't understand. I found this way out of the situation empirically.